# How to sum up the boolean values of a column in excel

Tags: excel, sum, boolean

I'm not expert in excel formulas but I know how programming works.
I saw this code.
    =SUMIF(B2:B25,">5")

I think this code sums up the value inside the cell that is greater than 5.
what I want to do is to count the cells in a column that is not null and display it to another cell.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=COUNTA(B2:B25)` will do it.

That counts the number of cells in a range that are *not* empty.